# post__in not working with pre_get_posts, but post__not_in does work

Tags: posts, query, pre-get-posts

I have an action setup on `pre_get_posts` which I would like to use `post__in` on.

I used the following code as a test:

```
$query->set('post__not_in', array(74485,1528,71460));
```

This works, the total number of posts is reduced by those 3. However, what if I want to use `post__in` to just return those 3 posts? I tried:

```
$query->set('post__in', array(74485,1528,71460));
```

But that didn't work. I thought maybe it was because `post__not_in` is already being used (as the codex says `post__in` and `post__not_in` can't be used together. So I tried:

```
$query->set('post__not_in', '');
$query->set('post__in', array(74485,1528,71460));
```

But this still doesn't work.

Any help please? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your actual question here. Are you trying to run two instances of `pre_get_posts` on the same query. If so, why? What are you trying to do

Comment: I'm trying to filter the results of a query using pre_get_posts. Currently lots of results are returned, I'd like to only include those 3 post IDs (just for testing purposes, I have a much larger array of post IDS I'd like returned). At the moment I can exclude post IDs with `post__not_in` (this also works with the large array of IDS I have) but I can't *include* only them. I suppose another way would be to get an array of all post ids and compare that to the array I have?

Comment: Are you using sticky posts

Comment: I'm not sure, how would I check? This is a woocommerce product loop, so post_type=product

Comment: I tried adding `$query->set('ignore_sticky_posts', 1);` but still no joy.

Comment: Well,your code works for me, so this must be a woocommerce issue then

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this with WooCommerce. I ended up passing the IDs I needed to a variable for safe keeping, and then hooking a function with extremely low priority. That worked fine. I figure woocommerce or what of my cleint's 8000000 plugins was overwriting post__in.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'assign_ids', 1000);
```

Comment: Cheers, that's a nice method. I ended up using a different solution in the end. Could I see your code for `assign_ids`?

Comment: MILION THANKS! the low priority solved my hugeeee problems!